# Cannot install Microsoft SQL Server 2012 prerequisites on Windows Server 2008 Core

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2012, windows-server-core, dism

I have the server with Windows Server 2008 core SP2 and I need to install SQL Server 2012 in it. The problem is that SQL Server requires .NET 4.5 and when I try to install .NET 4.5, the OS gives an error that says `"the program is not recognized."` To work around this, I tried to use `dism.exe`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I suggest reading this and then adding more detail to your question. http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault

Answer (score 7):

[This TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231669.aspx) outlines the requirements and procedure for installing Microsoft SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server core. As you'll see, 2008 is not listed as a supported operating system for this. This is because the .NET Frameworks required for this to run are only supported on core editions of 2008 R2 and later.